# Twig Excel Bundle autosize

Tags: excel, twig, bundle, autosize

How to set autosize in Twig Excel Bundle ? 
https://twigexcelbundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: What have your tried so far? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default `autoSize` property of a sheet to `true` via `columnDimension`:

```
{% xlssheet 'Worksheet' {
    columnDimension: {
        'default': {
            autoSize: true
        }
    }
}%}
    {# ... #}
{% endxlssheet %}
```

To define it for a specific column, use the letter of the desired column instead of `default`, per example the column D:

```
{% xlssheet 'Worksheet' {
    columnDimension: {
        'D': {
            autoSize: true
        }
    }
}%}
    {# ... #}
{% endxlssheet %}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Second example help me. But first didn't work =(

Comment: Strange, it's from the documentation... Anyway, glad it helped you!