# can't set row height and autosize for cell in TwigSpreadsheetBundle

Tags: symfony, phpspreadsheet

I'm a newbe for the TwigSpreadsheetBundle / PHPSpreadsheet
I couldn't find the right way to do format my excel export with TwigSpreadsheetBundle. I wanted to set autosize (height and width) for every cell.

The file consists only of one sheet. The first line is a header line for the user (I know I could have done it another way with the xlsdocument properties, but customer wants it this way.)

Second line is empty.
Third line is header line.

This is what I got from now:

```
{% set header1 = {
    font: {
        bold: true
    },
    borders: {
        bottom: {
            borderStyle: 'thin',
            color: {
                rgb: '000000'
            }
        }
    }
} %}
{% set header2 = {
    font: {
        bold: true
    }
} %}
{% xlsdocument {
    creator: user.username,
    modified: now
    } %}
    {% xlssheet 'Blatt 1'{
        columnDimension: {
            'default': {
                autoSize: true
            }
        }
    } %}
        {% xlsrow %}
            {% xlscell {
                style: { font: { size: '18' } },
                merge: 4
                } %}Angebot {{ offer.id }} - {{ offer.title }}{% endxlscell %}
        {% endxlsrow %}
        {% xlsrow %}
        {% endxlsrow %}
        {% xlsrow %}
            {% xlscell { style: header1 } %}Position{% endxlscell %}
            {% xlscell { style: header1 } %}Bezeichnung{% endxlscell %}
            {% xlscell { style: header1 } %}Verkaufspreis{% endxlscell %}
            {% xlscell { style: header1 } %}Montageeinkauf{% endxlscell %}
        {% endxlsrow %}
        {% for title in offer.titles %}
            {% xlsrow %}
                {% xlscell{ style: header2 } %}{{ title.position }}{% endxlscell %}
                {% xlscell{ style: header2 } %}{{ title.description }}{% endxlscell %}
                {% xlscell{ style: header2 } %}{{ title.salesPrice }}{% endxlscell %}
                {% xlscell{ style: header2 } %}{{ title.inputPriceAssembling }}{% endxlscell %}
            {% endxlsrow %}
            {% for item in title.items %}
                {% xlsrow %}
                    {% xlscell %}{{ title.position }}.{{ item.position }}{% endxlscell %}
                    {% xlscell %}{{ item.component.description }}{% endxlscell %}
                {% endxlsrow %}

            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endxlssheet %}
{% endxlsdocument %}
```

When I open the file in Libreoffice, OnlyOffice or Microsoft Office it looks like this:
[image: LibreOffice]
[image: OnlyOffice/Microsoft Office]

Comment: Using Twig to create a spreadsheet feels like a slow way of doing it.  TwigSpreadsheetBundle doesn't support Symfony 5 and doesn't look well maintained. Why don't you use PHPSpreadsheet without Twig?

Comment: It is an symfony 3.4 project. The project URL is https://github.com/erelke/TwigSpreadsheetBundle

Comment: Ok fair enough, that fork supports Symfony 5. Symfony 3.4 is very outdated and I think you'd better spend time upgrading it, instead of adding new features to an old version of a project.

Comment: And now on topic: it looks like you did exactly what the documentations tells you to do, so it should work. Is it working for some cells, or not at all?

Comment: I can't upgrade to symfony 4.x or 5 yet, there are other bundles used in project, that don't work (yet) for newer symfony versions.


On Topic: It seems all the Cells have standard width and height- none has the right size.

Comment: I added some pictures. I can see now, that the height is in Microsoft Office and Only Office OK, but the width isn't OK.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I found the answer 1hour ago. I don't know why I didn't find it earlier.

Comment: I understand. I marked it as duplicate just for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the documentation is not correct, "default" doesn't work, see also: [Second solution works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43187205/8398149)

```
{% xlssheet 'Blatt 1'{
        columnDimension: {
            'A': {
                autoSize: true
            },
            'B': {
                autoSize: true
            },
            'C': {
                autoSize: true
            },
            'D': {
                autoSize: true
            },
        }
    } %}
```

Comment: Yet another reason to look for an alternative to this bundle; it's documentations is not up to date ;)